# How to auto insert spaces between double brackets (double mustache) in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently when I add `{` to a `.html` file, VS Code will automatically close that bracket while leaving the cursor between the brackets, same with double curly brackets. Since I am working with Angular I would like to know if it is possible to have VS Code do this:

If I add 2 open curly brackets then add 2 blank spaces between them, close the brackets and set cursor between the blank spaces.

So instead of this: `{{|}}` I would get `{{ | }}` where `|` represents the cursor.

Comment: you can make your own snippets https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: Is it possible without `Ctrl+Space`? Like how it closes `{` automatically?

Comment: really dont know but. you can make your own vscode form and make custom changes cause the project its opensource.

Comment: you can do a custom snipped with ajs-expression and it insert the {{ | }} like you desires. iknow its more simpley only brakets., how i said before only with the cloned project you can edit the default snippets or functionality.

Answer (score 4):

"[Spaces Inside Braces](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AiryShift.spaces-inside-braces#overview)" seems to be the best bet currently.